# Intersection of open and compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In a metric space let $A$ be compact and $B$ - open, dense everywhere. Does it mean that
$$
\overline{A} = \overline{A\cap B}
$$
or there are counterexamples?

Comment: Note that compact sets in Hausdorff spaces are closed, so the left-hand side of your equation can be replaced by A.

Comment: Metric spaces are Hausdorff, so compact sets are closed. Therefore, $\overline{A}=A$. I know what "dense" and what "nowhere dense" mean. What does "dense everywhere" mean?

Comment: I think you might need the interior of $A$ to be non-empty.

Comment: Even with non-empty interior the statement is false - take $A = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ and $B = \mathbb{R} - \{2\}$.  You could ask that $A$ is equal to the closure of its interior, but then the statement is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the post; it reminds me to not jump to the conclusion that $ \overline{A\cap B}$=$\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$, and examples like A$=(0,1)$ and B=$(1,2)$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$?

I assume you use *everywhere dense* as a synonym to *dense* - like [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aEverywhere_Dense).

Perhaps this result is worth mentioning in this context: If $A$ is dense in $X$, then for every open $U\subset X$ we have $\overline U=\overline{U\cap A}$.